# iPhone 8 Plus (iOS 11.4) is frozen on emergency SOS screen

Tags: iphone, ios

Last evening I tried to add a system macroscript (Switch Control) recipe. After that my iPhone wasn't responding to any of touch moves. I managed to unlock it with Touch ID but I failed a couple of times and now it requires a password. I tried this:

1. Subtle click the volume UP button.
2. Subtle click the volume DOWN button.
3. Hold the startup button until you see apple logo.

Instead of force restart I'm stuck in emergency SOS screen mode. Touch interface doesn't work, force restart is not possible now. What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 11.4 is currently under development and you have either a developer or public beta installed on your device. Beta version of iOS are not guaranteed to work without issues.

Try restarting the device. If the issue persists, and it is hindering your workflow, it is recommended you restore the device to current public release of iOS, i.e. iOS 11.3.1.

You can share any observations and issue with Apple, via the Feedback app installed on your device.

[image]
<sub>(source: [imore.com](https://www.imore.com/sites/imore.com/files/styles/large/public/field/image/2015/07/ios-9-feedback-app-screen.jpg?itok=UtE2RjU8))</sub>

Comment: I can't restart my device as touch interface does not perform.

Comment: You can force restart your device. Just press and hold both the Sleep/Wake and Home buttons simultaneously for at least 10 seconds, until you see the Apple logo. You can let go of both buttons after the Apple logo appears.

Comment: And what for iPhone 8 Plus? This method work for iPhone 7 plus and lower.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect instructions. To force restart iPhone 8 Plus, press and release the Volume Up button, press and release the Volume Down button, and press and hold the Side button until your device reboots, then release. Instructions source: https://9to5mac.com/2017/10/11/iphone-8-how-to-force-restart-recovery-dfu-mode/

Answer (score 3):

If you have this problem — here is solution:

1. Press Volume Up then Volume Down, then hold the Power button till the screen becomes black.
2. Do the first step while screen is black.
3. Done — iPhone reboots.

Answer (score 1):

For the iPhone 8, just hold Siri and tell her to call someone you know. When it’s calling just keep pressing the home button and/or just end the call. Worked for me and it might work for you

Answer (score -1):

iOS 11.4 is the beta vision, so go feedback and reboot